# Showing that an element of a polynomial ring is irreducible

Tags: abstract-algebra, integral-domain, unique-factorization-domains

> Show that $x^2 − y^3$ is irreducible in $K[x, y]$ and conclude that $K[x, y]/(x^2 − y^3$) is an integral domain.

I honestly don't know how to approach this problem
I just know that i have to use the fact that $K[x, y]$ is a UFD.

Comment: Eisenstein’s criterion can help.

Comment: Isn't Eisenstein's criterion over $\mathbb{Q}$?

Comment: @JJR One version of Eisenstein's criterion is that if $R$ is a UFD and the polynomial $f = \sum_{i = 0}^n a_i X^i$ is primitive (the gcd of its coefficients is 1) and there is a prime $P$ of $R$ such that $a_0 \in P \setminus P^2$ and $a_i \in P$ for $i < n$ and $a_n \notin P$ then $f$ is irreducible in $R[X]$.

Answer (score 2):

The polynomial $x^2-y^3$ is irreducible in $(K(y))[x]$, since it is a quadric without a root over a field. Hence the polynomial is prime and the quotient is an integral domain.